# parse_tax_query causing Navigation Menu To Disappear

Tags: wp-query, menus

I am using the following snippet to modify a query...

```
function no_child_terms($query) {
    if( !is_admin())    {
  $query->tax_query->queries[0]['include_children'] = 0;
  }
}
add_action('parse_tax_query', 'no_child_terms');
```

This is working correctly and it is modifying the query correctly but it is causing my navigation menu to disappear.  Am I using parse_tax_query correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parsing happens on every query run on a page, not just the main query. Your `parse_tax_query` is modifying the query for menu items in your menu. Check `is_main_query()` to make sure you only change the main query:

```
function no_child_terms($query) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->tax_query->queries[0]['include_children'] = 0;
    }
}
add_action('parse_tax_query', 'no_child_terms');
```

Comment: Typo man for is_man_query to is_main_query, but apart from that its perfect!  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: oops, fixed. you're welcome!